# Сколько ViewModel передать во View

Tags: ооп, mvvm, архитектура, проектирование

Есть ViewModel_1 которая возвращает список объектов типа Animal, данные о них она берет из хранилища объектов Dog, которые превращается в пригодный для биндинга на вьюшку Animal. Так же в ней есть метод "giveStone" который вызывает методы менеджера специфического для Dog.
Есть ViewModel_2 которая также возвращает список объектов типа Animal, данные о них она берет из другого хранилища, например Cat. В ней есть метод "sayMyau".
Есть ViewModel_3 которая собственно агрегирует в себя данные из 1ой и 2ой модели и отдает их на рендеринг.
Вопрос - что отдавать во вьюшку? Она знает, что у нее Dog или Cat (Animal - по сути декоратор) и знает какие методы можно выполнять над объектом. Есть несколько вариантов:
1) Отдавать ViewModel_3 в которой прописать прокси вызовы первых двух моделей - страшно, громоздко..
2) Отдавать все три модели, но тогда нарушаются правила ООП (компонент имеет доступ к тем методам, которые ему не нужны)
3) Отдавать VievModel_3 с гетерами на 1 и 2. Почти тоже самое что и вариант 1, но без проксей.

P.S> Предупреждая вопрос - а зачем так делать приведу яркий пример. Возьмем тот же Viber - у него есть список, в котором как личные чаты так и групповые. Объекты разных сущностней отображаются в одном списке но с каждым из типов можно совершать разные действия.

Answer (score 0):

Отдавайте все три модели. Поскольку в них есть общие методы, вынесите их в общий интерфейс, и пусть View работает с интерфейсом.

Никакого нарушения здесь не будет: View не знает, придёт ли к нему `ViewModel_1` или `ViewModel_2`, и пользуется лишь методами интерфейса.